# Check id user into two fields with get and request

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i want create `if validation` in my `views` to check before to site they are matched,but
if someone is matched together:
Models.py

```
class Matched(models.Model):
     profile_user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='profile_user')
     matched_user = models.ForeignKey(Profile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='matched_user')
```

and model is with UniqueConstraint

but my views

```
def profileDetailView(request, pk):
   user = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
   if request.user.is_authenticated:
     pass
```

and my question is to check in `if` `user` and `request.user` are in `Matched Model`, i mean i can do it like that:
`x = Matched.object.filter(profile_user=user, matched_user=request.user.profile)`
`y = Matched.object.filter(profile_user=request.user.profile, matched_user=user)`

and
`if x or y: pass`

but its some more optimaze option for do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [exists()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#exists) to be more efficient like this:

```py
x = Matched.object.filter(profile_user=user, matched_user=request.user.profile).exists()
y = Matched.object.filter(profile_user=request.user.profile, matched_user=user).exists()

if x or y:
    # a match exists
```

Comment: About it i know, but i think do it without creating two verb, but if it will be good enought so okay

Comment: You can use Q objects to do that but it adds some complexity: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects